# Python Asyncio Websocket not detecting a disconnect on wifi but does on localhost

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

```
async def relayHandler(request):
print('Websocket connection starting')
ws = aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse(autoclose=True)
await ws.prepare(request)
print('Websocket connection ready')

async for msg in ws:
    print(msg)
    if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
        print(msg.data)
        if msg.data == 'close':
            await ws.close()
        else:
            await ws.send_str(msg.data + '/answer')
    elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
        print('ws connection closed with exception %s' %ws.exception())
print('Websocket connection closed')
return ws
```

this is my websocket handler it uses aiohttp on top of asyncio. The problem is if i disconnect the clients wifi connection its not detecting that the connection is lost. i also tried using the Websockets module, but the same thing happend. But when the client is  on localhost then working perfectly.
Whats the main reason for this, and if anyone could explain how to properly catch network exceptions inside asyncio.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; ping your server by client.

That's how TCP stack works: graceful disconnection requires sending a packet to peer. If the network is broken not data transfer is available.

Localhost network has all the knowledge about disconnections but real network misses the info about all moving parts.

The only reliable way to detect disconnection is waiting for a message from peer (it can be *ping* message or regular data packet) with a timeout.

If timeout is expired -- the peer is gone, the local end of communication channel should be closed as well.

That's why any long-living communication over TCP is a little more complex than it seems -- all production-level systems use pings and timeouts internally. It affects not only websockets but any messengers with custom protocol.

Comment: Thnks Andrew, i understand that we hav to ping the system, but can u explain how this is different when on localhost, and more importantly why no exception is thrown when the connection is ended, internally somewhere asyncio or web-sockets are checking for if the stream has data, if the stream doesn't exist it should throw an exception.

Comment: @NivedPv That's because TCP is built upon connectionless, stateless IP protocol - under the hood it is just throwing self-contained IP packets. So if you are waiting for data from your peer, TCP can't tell difference between destroyed connection and healthy connection with peer that hasn't sent any data to you yet. So the only way to check connection health - send anything and check for reaction

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky Thats the thing, thank u so much, so if your listening for messages we cant say if the connection is droppped. Thanks So much, and can i solve this using ping in websocket to check if the clients online or i have to create a custom message to which the client has to respond with an acknowledgement.